# Possible to compose a large transaction in Django then commit to DB later?

Tags: python, django

I have a long set of model creations which are going slowly due to remote DB access.  Is it possible to set some kind of transaction start and end and then commit?

Comment: you are contacting the database also if you defer commit. In any case to create a transaction you simply decorate your function with `@atomic`

Comment: If you have performance problems with object creation it is probably better to use bulk create https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create